# Object.create instead of Constructors for inheritance

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

I want to be able to learn creating Objects per the new JavaScript ECMA 5 standards, and use them in my current projects, without breaking functionality. But I see un-explainable stuff that makes me afraid

Consider the following code:

```
var foo = {
        oldProp: 'ECMA Script 3',
        newProp: 'ECMA Script 5'
    };

// The new way of inheritance
var bar = Object.create( foo );

// and of assigning properties, if I am right
var bar2 = Object.create( Object.prototype, {
        oldProp: { value: 'ECMA Script 3'},
        newProp: { value: 'ECMA Script 5'}
    });

// and then
bar; 
// console output
Object {oldProp: "ECMA Script 3", newProp: "ECMA Script 5"}

// whereas !!
bar2;
Object {} // Why this?
```

Also,

```
bar.hasOwnProperty('oldProp');  // false, whereas
bar2.hasOwnProperty('oldProp'); // true !! It should be the other way round, right?
```

Additionally, I am not able to change the property of `bar2`

```
bar2.oldProp = "Marry had a little lamb";
bar2.oldProp; // "ECMA Script 3"
```

And more --

```
for (k in bar2) console.log(bar2[k]) // undefined
```

---

**Am I creating the Objects in a correct way**?
What I basically want to achieve is getting rid of constructors.

Old code:

```
var Slideshow = function(type) {
    this.type = type;
    this.deleteSlideshow = function() {
        // some code
    }
}
Slideshow.prototype.nextSlide = function() {
    // lotsa code
}
var vanityFairSlideshow = new Slideshow('wide-screen');
```

I want to change to `Object.create`, may be kind of this:

```
var Slideshow = Object.create({ /* prototype */ }, { /* properties and methods */ });
var vanityFairSlideshow = Object.create( Slideshow , { /* properties and methods */ });
```

Whats the proper way of doing it?

Comment: *Why* do you want to get rid of constructors?

Comment: @Bergi, Only for the sake of learning modern JavaScript, which emphasizes on the same. Do not mistake me for a traitor mate. I have consistently coded Prototypal Inheritance for long with the Constructor way being basis of the structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem here is the defaults for the [descriptors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) (aside from `value`) that you omitted for each property.

Using this syntax (like for `defineProperty` and `defineProperties`), [`writable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Writable_attribute) is `false` by default, and [`enumerable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Enumerable_attribute) is `false`.

Setting both of these to `true` will result in the behaviour you expect.

```
var bar2 = Object.create( Object.prototype, {
    oldProp: { value: 'ECMA Script 3', writable: true, enumerable: true}
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YZmbg/

Also, hopefully you appreciate how this isn't supported in all browsers; note the [compatibility table for `Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create#Cross-browser_compatibility). Shims which adhere to the `writable` and `configurable` properties do not, and cannot, exist.

<sup>Finally, +1 for such a well written question; it's a breath of fresh air.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

I'll try to answer on this question:

> **Am I creating the Objects in a correct way?** What I basically want to achieve is getting rid of constructors.

First small example. Imagine that we have this simple structure:

```
var Slideshow = function(type) {
  this.type = type;
}

Slideshow.prototype.nextSlide = function() {
    console.log('next slide');
}

Slideshow.prototype.deleteSlideshow = function() {
    console.log('delete slideshow');
}

var AdvancedSlideshow = function(bgColor) {
    this.bgColor = bgColor;
}

AdvancedSlideshow.prototype.showMeBgColor = function() {
    console.log('bgColor iS: ' + bgColor);
}
```

Now we want `AdvancedSlideshow` to inherit from `Slideshow`. So we want all functions from parent available for instances of its child. Without `Object.create` we did it like that:

```
// THIS CODE ISNT CORRECT
// code for slideshow is same

var AdvancedSlideshow = function(type, bgColor) {
    // this line can supply whole Slideshow constructor
    Slideshow.call( this, type ); 

    this.bgColor = bgColor;
}

AdvancedSlideshow.prototype = Slideshow.prototype; // there problems start!!!!

AdvancedSlideshow.prototype.showMeBgColor = function() { // we did augumentation of Slideshow
    console.log('bgColor is: ' + bgColor);
}
```

Now `AdvancedSlideshow` inherits everything from `Slideshow`, but **also `Slideshow` inherits everything from `AdvancedSlideshow`**. That is what we **don't want**.

```
var simpleSlideshow = new Slideshow('simple');
simpleSlideshow.showMeBgColor(); // ReferenceError: bgColor is not defined
                                 // but function exists and that's wrong!
```

So we have to use something more complicated. There is a polyfill made by Douglas Crockford a long time ago.

```
if (!Object.create) {
    Object.create = function (o) {
        if (arguments.length > 1) {
            throw new Error('Object.create implementation only accepts the first parameter.');
        }
        function F() {}
        F.prototype = o;
        return new F();
    };
}
```

Well first it wasn't polyfill, it was small pattern and it looked like otherwise. But pattern was evolving and then it was so good that it became part of javascript. So now we have just a polyfill for browsers that doesn't support ecmascript-5. And we can code:

```
// THIS IS CORRECT
AdvancedSlideshow.prototype = Object.create(Slideshow.prototype);
```

instead of

```
function F() {};
F.prototype = Slideshow.prototype;
AdvancedSlideshow.prototype = new F();
```

Then `AdvancedSlideshow` inherits from `Slideshow` but **`Slideshow` doesn't inherit from `AdvancedSlideshow`**.

**So purpose of `Object.create` isn't to get rid of constructors or "new" keywords. Its purpose is to make correct prototype chain!**

**EDIT 20.2.2014:**
Few days ago I realised, that `constructor` property is part of the prototype chain. So if we use `Object.create` for inheritance, we also change `constructor` property (not the constructor itself, just a property) of our child object. Therefore constructor property of new instance of child object points its parent. We can fix that with simple `Child.prototype.constructor = Child`.

```
...
Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);
Child.prototype.constructor = Child;

var first = new Child();
first.constructor === Child; // true
first.constructor === Parent; // false
first instanceOf Child; // true
first instanceOf Parent; // true
```

Now, there is a second parameter for Object.create which allows you to make lets say "hidden secrets" of objects. But I **don't recommend** you to do this, because you don't need it. It is something advanced that also works like some patterns.

If you want to avoid constructor, "new" keyword or anything important, then you are probably looking for some factory pattern. But remember, for example "new" has some weaknesses but pattern for removing built-in features are usually worse! Anyway, maybe you can find some inspiration here:

http://www.2ality.com/2010/12/javascripts-prototypal-inheritance.html

Comment: +1 for detailed explanation. However, I am accepting the other answer as which says I had missed the **property descriptors**. PS: being Czech, your grammar is considerably good. :)

Answer (score 1):

`bar`is created without any property and `foo`as its prototype, so `bar.hasOwnProperty('oldProp');`consequently returns false.

For `bar2`you don't provide descriptors and the default value for `enumerable` and writable is `false`. So you can't change the properties or enumerate them in a `for...in` loop.

As for *Am I creating the Objects in a correct way?*: What you are doing is reasonable. You create `Slideshow`as a prototype for all slideshows and create a slideshow with this prototype and additional properties.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> bar2 // logs Object {}
> ```
>
> I am not able to change the property of bar2
>
> ```
> for (k in bar2) console.log(bar2[k]) // undefined
> ```

That is because the second argument to `Object.create` resembles [`Object.defineProperties`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties) - and that means you are using [property descriptors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Description). While you are only setting the *value*, the `enumerable`, `writable` and `configurable` flags default to `false`.

> Whats the proper way of doing it?

Either you explicitly set the `enumberable` and `writable` flags explicitly to `true`, or you don't use the second parameter:

```
 var bar2 = Object.create( Object.prototype ); // or Slideshow.prototype or whatever
 bar2.oldProp = 'ECMA Script 3';
 bar2.newProp = 'ECMA Script 5';
```

However, if this looks too lengthy to you, you would use a factory utility function - basically a constructor.