# Javascript prototype - object.create issue

Tags: javascript

Im trying to learn about object.create and prototypal inheritance and have the following:

```
var Employee = {
    'attributes': {},
    getAttributes: function() {
        return this.attributes;
    },
    addAttribute: function(attribute) {
        if (! this.attributes.hasOwnProperty(attribute)) {
            this.attributes.extend(attribute);
        }
    }
};

var OfficeEmployee = Object.create(Employee);

var OfficeEmployeeInstance = Object.create(OfficeEmployee, {'attributes': {'id': 123, 'name': 'Bob'}});

console.log(OfficeEmployeeInstance.attributes);

OfficeEmployeeInstance.addAttribute({'salary': '100'});

console.log(OfficeEmployeeInstance.getAttributes());
```

It doesnt work as i expect it should though and throws errors:

```
console.log(OfficeEmployeeInstance.attributes);
```

is undefined

and

```
 console.log(OfficeEmployeeInstance.getAttributes());
```

gives error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined tester.js:39
Employee.addAttribute tester.js:39
(anonymous function)
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: `this.attributes.extend`. What is `extend`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Object.create instead of Constructors for inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16187072/object-create-instead-of-constructors-for-inheritance)

Comment: Are you sure you want to create instances with instence specific member on the prototype? I know you provide attributes when you create an instance but you should know that they also exist on the prototype and if you don't shadow them you can get unexpected results: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941

Comment: Isnt that the point of inheritance though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument of `Object.create` has to be a properties object. That's an object with a defined structure and specific properties:

```
var OfficeEmployeeInstance = Object.create(OfficeEmployee, {
       'attributes': {
           value: {'id': 123, 'name': 'Bob'},
           writeable: true,
           enumerable: true
       }
    });
```

You can find the supported properties [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty).

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create

When using .create you should pass it an argument of someObject.prototype, rather than a constructor name.  The documentation above should help.